# How to loop to generate string in sequence?

Tags: python, string, loops, automation

I am trying to create a loop where I can generate string using loop. What I am trying to achieve is that I want to create a small collection of strings starting from 1 character to up to 5 characters.

So, starting from sting `1`, I want to go to `55555` but this is number so it seems easy if I just add them, but when it comes to alpha numeric, it gets tricky.

Here is explanation,

I have collection of alpha-numeric chars as string `s = "123ABC"` and what I want to do is that I want to create all possible 1 character string out of it, so I will have `1`,`2`,`3`,`A`,`B`,`C` and after that I want to add one more digit in length of string so I can get `11`, `12`, `13` and so on until I get all possible combination out of it up to `CA`, `CB`, `CC` and I want to get it up to `CCCCCC`. I am confused in loop because I can get it to generate a temp sting but looping inside to rotate characters is tricky,

this is what I have done so far,

```
i = 0

strr = "123ABC"

while i < len(strr):
    t = strr[0] * (i+1)
    for q in range(0, len(t)):
        # Here I need help to rotate more
        pass
    i += 1
```

Can anyone explain me or point me to resource where I can find solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nested loop. Different depths of recursion produce all possible combinations.

```
strr = "123ABC"

def prod(items, level):
    if level == 0:
        yield []
    else:
        for first in items:
            for rest in prod(items, level-1):
                yield [first] + rest

for ln in range(1, len(strr)+1):
    print("length:", ln) 
    for s in prod(strr, ln):
        print(''.join(s))
```

It is also called [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and there is a corresponding function in `itertools`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function:

```
import itertools

chars = '123ABC'
for i in xrange(1, len(chars)+1):
    print list(itertools.permutations(chars, i))
```

EDIT:
To get a list of strings, try this:

```
import itertools

chars = '123ABC'
strings = []
for i in xrange(1, len(chars)+1):
    strings.extend(''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(chars, i))
```

Comment: It kinda works, but not the way I expected. For example, for 3 character string, I can have `122` or `AAA` but this is not giving that as a string or for six character string not `CCCCCC`.

Comment: try combinations_with_replacement() instead permutations. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Comment: It kinda solved my problem but I found one more thing, for 2 character string, i get 11, 12, 13, and than 22, 23 and than 33. not 21, not 31, 32.